# Migrate VB6 Data Report to Crystal Report within VS.NET

Tags: vb.net, vb6, crystal-reports, vb6-migration

I am trying to convert a VB6 Data Report (.dsr file) to a Crystal Report through the migration process within Visual Studio. I have read articles that reference adding a Data Report to a Project from Visual Studio 2005/2008 and that it will convert the Data Report to a Crystal Report, but I have not been successful in doing so. Does the VB6 Data Environment need to be converted too? Has anyone been able to do this successfully and if so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the steps outlined [here](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/dotnet-vb-upgrade/613/VB6-Data-Reports-DSR-to-VB-NET-RPT-Files) (2nd to last post)?

Comment: Yes, I have tried that, and it didn't work for me. Have you been able to make a successful conversion?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  We had VB6 data reports on a smaller project ~5 years ago and could not upgrade them, so our tech team rewrote the reports.

Comment: I don't have a copy of VB6 anymore, but is the DSR file format ASCII formatted?  If so, you might be able to write a program that reads the file and writes a Crystal Report definition file ...

Comment: The DSR file is plain text, but I'm not sure that writing a program is the right answer. It's frustrating that it is readable, but the conversion process isn't working.